# How to apply rate limits on backend configuration in krakenD

Tags: devops, endpoint, rate-limiting, krakend

I have a krakend configuration for endpoint as below

```
        {
            "endpoint": "/api/login",
            "method": "POST",
            "output_encoding": "no-op",
            "headers_to_pass": [
              "*"
            ],
            "backend": [
                {
                    "encoding": "no-op",
                    "host": [ "http://login-service:80" ],
                    "url_pattern": "/api/login",
                    "method": "POST",
            "extra_config": {
      "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-ratelimit/juju/router": {
          "maxRate": 2,
          "capacity": 2,
          "clientMaxRate": 1,
          "strategy": "header",
          "key": "x-real-ip"
      }
      }
                }
            ]
        }
```

I followed these links to form the configuration
https://www.krakend.io/docs/backends/rate-limit/
https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/rate-limit/

But the issue is that I don't see the configuration working.
For the above config, the maximum allowed requests per second would be 2, but, the endpoint accepts more than 2 requests per second without showing any error message. According to the docs, it should show 503 Service Unavailable if the maxRate limit is reached to whoever triggered the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your extra configuration is misplaced.
The router rate limit goes inside the endpoint, not the backend. Use this:

```
{
    "endpoint": "/api/login",
    "method": "POST",
    "output_encoding": "no-op",
    "headers_to_pass": [
        "*"
    ],
    "extra_config": {
        "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-ratelimit/juju/router": {
            "maxRate": 2,
            "capacity": 2,
            "clientMaxRate": 1,
            "strategy": "header",
            "key": "x-real-ip"
        }
    },
    "backend": [
        {
            "encoding": "no-op",
            "host": [
                "http://login-service:80"
            ],
            "url_pattern": "/api/login",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```